# Adding Cooldowns to Python 2

Tags: python

I asked how to make a cooldown before, but I am still somewhat of a beginner in Python. Could someone suggest a way to make a cooldown with an example? What I mean by a cooldown is so somebody could still use a command with something else still charging. An example is this:

```
while True:
    dummy=300
    standopt=input("Choose between TWHV and SP (DUMMY MECHANIC UNFINISHED FOR SP).\nIf you already chose a Stand, you're choosing again due to the dummy's hospitalisation.")
    if standopt=="TWHV" or standopt=="twhv" or standopt=="Twhv":
            while True:
                if dummy>=1:
                    Action = str(input("Your Stand awaits instructions...(e, r)"))
                    if Action=="e" or Action=="E":
                        print("Barrage (28)")
                        dummy=dummy-28
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
                    elif Action=="r" or Action=="R":
                        print("Heavy Punch (30)")
                        dummy=dummy-30
                        print("Your dummy is now on",dummy,"HP.")
```

What I want is for the code to keep running, but have a simple way of putting one of the commands on a timer before it runs out and is able to be used again, while in the meantime, other moves could be used.

Comment: What's a "cooldown"?....Quick search came up with [lots of potential answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+cooldown+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are still using Python 2.x? You're aware that it hasn't been officially supported for quite some time now, yes?

Comment: I didn't realise it said python 2.x, it was supposed to be python, specifically version 3.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I set up two functions to update the cooldown time and to check if the action is available for use. We will use a dictionary to store the available time of every action.

```py
import time

cooldown = {}

def update(action, cool):
    cooldown.update({action: time.time() + cool})

def validate(action):
    return cooldown.get(action, 0) - time.time() <= 0
```

You can learn more about the [`dict.get`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) and [`dict.update`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp) method.

### Implementation

We will try it out on the punch function.

```py
def punch():
    if validate("punch"):
        print("Heavy Punch.")
        update("punch", cool=5)
    else:
        print("Cooling down.")
```

### Demonstration

Let's do two simultaneous punches, wait for six seconds, and then punch again. The first two punches are done simultaneously so it does not allow you to punch the second time. However, after you wait for six seconds, the punch ability is already cooled down (the cooldown time is five seconds).

```py
punch()
punch()

time.sleep(6)

punch()
```

It gives the following result.

```
Heavy Punch.
Cooling down.
Heavy Punch.
```

---

### The complete code

To apply it to your use case, you can do the following.

```py
cooldown = {}

def update(action, cool):
    cooldown.update({action: time.time() + cool})

def validate(action):
    return cooldown.get(action, 0) - time.time() <= 0

while True:
    dummy = 300
    standopt = input("Choose between TWHV and SP (DUMMY MECHANIC"
        "UNFINISHED FOR SP).\nIf you already chose a Stand, you're"
        "choosing again due to the dummy's hospitalisation.")

    if standopt.lower() == "twhv":
        while True:
            if dummy >= 1:
                action = str(input("Your Stand awaits instructions...(e, r)"))

                if validate(action):
                    if action.lower() == "e":
                        print("Barrage (28)")
                        dummy -= 28
                        print("Your dummy is now on", dummy, "HP.")
                    elif action.lower() == "r":
                        print("Heavy Punch (30)")
                        dummy -= 30
                        print("Your dummy is now on", dummy, "HP.")

                    update(action, cool=5)
                else:
                    print("Cooling down.")
```

Comment: is there any way to prevent the use of time.sleep? The problem is I want to be able to put a cooldown on 1 move when used, but then be able to use a different move as well while it cools down.

Comment: @Saturdatwal This approach doesn't use `time.sleep`. It is just used for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks very much then!

Comment: It did work, but if you could please also explain how the function works so I can adapt it into my full code, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Saturdatwal It's not really the punch function that does the cooldown process. The idea is to wrap the action around an if-statement and update the cooldown at the end. I have added the complete code.

Comment: One more question, is there any way I can add multiple cooldowns in an optimal way other than just adding multiple functions and dictionaries? I'd also like to note that there are at least 9 commands for the code

Comment: @Saturdatwal I'm not sure what you mean. The dictionary, the update, and the validate functions are only initialized **once**. If you want to add more commands, go ahead and add another `elif action.lower() == ...` block below without having to do anything at all.

Comment: I want the commands to have separate cooldowns instead of being shared. e.g. after using the R (Heavy Punch), I could use the E (Barrage) right after if I wished to, having to wait out both cooldowns before I can use both again, so I assumed there would need to be multiple dictionaries so the cooldowns can be distinguished between more easily.

Comment: @Saturdatwal No, not really. You only need one dictionary. Try adding more commands, play around with it, and you will see.

Comment: It says time isn't def

Comment: @Saturdatwal Oh, you need to `import time`

Comment: Don't worry, I did fix that, but thank you very much for helping me. Currently finishing off the cooldown mechanic and off to a new mechanic which I also need help with. Thanks!